# Closing a connection to a NAS on startup

Tags: windows, batch-file, authentication, nas

Im trying to find a solution to the following Problem.

Assume there are 10 employees, everyone has their own username and password on the company-internal NAS. Now Employee A get himself a Laptop, logs into the windows user 'Employees' that everyone uses, logs into the NAS with his username j_doe and password 123456 and navigates to his own folder. He does some work at a Excel Sheet and now shuts the Laptop down.

Now Employee B comes and wants to make some changes to his Word Doc that he stored into his own folder. He happens to take the same Laptop as Employee A did, boots, logs into the same windows user, and oh, he doesnt need to log into NAS. But as soon as he tries to access folders j_doe had no access to, the NAS prompts him with a login. He enters his username and password and the NAs replies that he cant log into 2 diffrent users fromt he same Computer.

What I need to do is somehow delete all stored login data to that NAS using a Batch script running as autostart?

I got that batch in autostart clear but im missing the right command to do that

Answer (score 0):

The command you need is `net use`

```
C:\Users\XXX>net use /?
The syntax of this command is:

NET USE
[devicename | *] [\\computername\sharename[\volume] [password | *]]
        [/USER:[domainname\]username]
        [/USER:[dotted domain name\]username]
        [/USER:[username@dotted domain name]
        [/SMARTCARD]
        [/SAVECRED]
        [[/DELETE] | [/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}]]

NET USE {devicename | *} [password | *] /HOME

NET USE [/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}]
```

So to remove the drive use:

```
NET USE \\MyServerName\Share /DELETE
```

or to delete a drive mapped as X:

```
NET USE X /DELETE
```

Comment: I tried this already, it disconnects the drive but does not delete the login credentials. Means when I connect again, it auto-logs in with the same log in data